# Multiple sampling with different sizes on Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to implement this code so it works as quickly as possible.

Say I have a population of 100 different values, you can think of it as `pop = 1:100` or `pop = randn(1,100)` to keep things simple. I have a vector `n` which gives me the size of samples I want to get. Say, for example, that `n=[1 3 10 6 2]`. What I want to do is to take 5 (which in reality is  `length(n)`) different samples of `pop`, each consisting of `n(i)` elements without replacement. This means that for my first sample I want 1 element out of `pop`, for the second sample I want 3, for the third I want 10, and so on.

To be honest, I am not really interested in which elements are sampled. What I want to get is the sum of those elements that are present in the *i*th-sample. This would be trivial if I implemented it with a loop, but I am trying to avoid using them to keep my code as quick as possible. I have to do this for many different populations and with `length(n)`being very large.

If I had to do it with a loop, this would be how:

```
pop = randn(1,100);
n = [1 3 10 6 2];
sum_sample = zeros(length(n),1);
for i = 1:length(n)
  sum_sample(i,1) = sum(randsample(pop,n(i)));
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't make assumptions. Update your post with a real example, real values, and an minimal code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: So take `pop = randn(1:100)` and `n=[1 3 10 6 2]`. I just edited my question to introduce how I would do it on a loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that vectorizing or using things like arrayfun typically creates overhead. Hence, vectorizing such a tiny calculation might actually slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to figure out what is fastest for you is to do a comparison of the different methods.

In fact **the loop appears to be very fast** in this case!

```
pop = randn(1,100);
n = [1 3 10 6 2];

tic
sr = @(n) sum(randsample(pop,n));
sum_sample = arrayfun(sr,n);
toc %% Returns about 0.004

clear su
tic
for t=numel(n):-1:1
    su(t)=sum(randsample(pop,n(t)));
end
toc %% Returns about 0.003
```

Comment: To do performance analysis I would suggest larger dimensions. I tried the code with `pop=randn(1,100000)` and `n=randi(100000,1,10000)` and get almost identical run times for the two cases. From that I assume that MATLAB internally realizes `arrayfun` by going through the array in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function handle which choses the random samples and sums these up. Then you can use arrayfun to execute this function for all values of n:

```
pop = randn(1,100);
n = [1 3 10 6 2];
sr = @(n) sum(randsample(pop,n));
sum_sample = arrayfun(sr,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
pop = randn(1,100);
n = [1 3 10 6 2];
sampled_data_index = randi(length(pop),1,sum(n));
sampled_data = pop(sampled_data_index);
```

The `randi` function randomly selects integer values in a specified range that is suitable for indexing. After you have the indices you can use those at once to sample the data from the `pop` database.

If you want to have **unique** indices you can replace the `randi` function with `randperm`:

```
sampled_data_index = randperm(length(pop),sum(n));
```

**Finally:**

You can have all the sampled values as a cell variable using the following code:

```
pop = randn(1,100);
n = [1 3 10 6 2];
fun = @(m) pop(randperm(length(pop),m));
C = arrayfun(fun,n,'UniformOutput',0)
```

Also having the sum of the sampled data:

```
funs = @(m) sum(pop(randperm(length(pop),m)));
sumC = arrayfun(funs,n)
```

Comment: I was also thinking about your first approach, but it gets a bit messy if you want uniqueness in each sample but not neccesarily in the union of all samples (I believe this is how the loop of the asker currently works). If that is not an issue, this should be quite fast.

Comment: if you use the last 2 lines of code, for each function-execution the samples would be unique. If I am getting what you saying right.